# What will happen if we delete an array after increment the pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

```
int main(){

int *p=new int[5];

//case 1: delete p;
//case 2: p++;delete[] p;


return 0;
}
```

What will happen if I use case 1 and case 2 separately ?

Comment: It probably depends a lot on which flag you're using during compilation.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. Use `delete[]` with `new[]` and `delete` with `new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What will happen

Case 1: Undefined behaviour.

`p` was not returned by the call to `new` (but instead by `new[]`), so `delete p;` is UB.

---

Case 2: Undefined behaviour.

`p+1` was not returned by the call to `new[]`, so `p++;delete[] p;` is UB.

Answer (score 0):

You may free memory that you didn't allocate.
You have to call delete on the same pointer-value that you got back using new

Comment: No. It is undefined. It may free memory, it may do something else.

Comment: still my second statement is correct. just consider the 'will' as a 'may'